# Finding VMWare VMX file

Tags: vmware-fusion

I'm running VMWare Fusion under Snow Leopard. Where can I find the VMX file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VMWare have a KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014782) to help -

> To edit a .vmx file:
>
> 1. Ensure the virtual machine is shut down (not suspended).
> 2. From Fusion's menu bar, click Window > Virtual Machine Library.
> 3. In the left column, Ctrl+click the virtual machine and click Show in Finder.
> 4. Ctrl+click the revealed package (ending in .vmwarevm) and click Show Package Contents.
> 5. Ctrl+click the file ending in .vmx and choose Open With > Other.
> 6. Navigate to TextEdit and click Choose.
> 7. You can now add or edit lines lines as needed. Lines are displayed in no particular order.
> 8. When finished, save changes, and exit.